# How to flush a TFileStream?

Tags: delphi, buffer, flush, tfilestream

TFileStream provides buffered output, which is great in most cases, but in some cases (especially during debugging) it's nice to flush the buffer immediately.  Thing is, I don't know of any way to do that except calling Free, which is kind of counterproductive.

Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need to flush the stream. Try:

```
 FlushFileBuffers(fs.Handle);
```

? Did you see/try this?

Answer (score 7):

It's a bit involved, but you can actually control a lot of that behavior in the call to (win32 api) CreateFile. You can add `FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH` / `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING` or even provide optimization hints to the cache system with `FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN` or `FILE_FLAG_RANDOM_ACCESS`. To use TFileStream that way, I think you'd need to override the Create to change how it obtains the file handle. FWIW, FlushFileBuffers is equivalent to a Close/Open on the file. If you're doing a lot of activity with repeated flushes, it will slow the code down considerably.

A bit of documentation [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/99794)

Comment: Actually, you do not need to override constructor. There already is an overloaded version, which accepts a file handle. So, you must proceed as follows (error handling removed):

FS := TFileStream.Create( CreateFile( PChar(FileName), ... , FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH, ... ) );

That's all. Really simple.

Answer (score 6):

I think altCognito's answer (FlushFileBuffers) is probably the best, but only because TFileStream does no buffering by itself. For other, buffered, streams should first look if the stream offers a Flush method. And as a last resort you could probably use the old trick of Seek(Begin) and then Seek(CurrentPos).

Answer (score 2):

Are you using a TWriter/TReader or just going straight for the TFileStream interface? TReader and TWriter have internal buffers. But for a normal filestream then the replies above have it sorted. I personally would implement my own stream with methods to deal with it directly.